# SQL Syntax error when executing

Tags: sql, if-statement, not-exists

I've tried everything that could have an impact on the syntax, but nothing worked. I want to run this script to add an entry to a table called pm_Permissions. However, when I run it again, and the entry already exists, I don't want it to be added again.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pm_Permissions WHERE permission_tag = 'dbcorrectstructure')
BEGIN

    LOCK TABLES `pm_Permissions` WRITE;
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pm_Permissions` DISABLE KEYS */;
    INSERT INTO `pm_Permissions` VALUES (NULL,'dbCorrectStructure', 'Makes sure all the correct tables, columns and entries exist','dbcorrectstructure','$sourcedir/administration.lib.php','dbCorrectStructure','Administration',0);
    /*!40000 ALTER TABLE `pm_Permissions` ENABLE KEYS */;
    UNLOCK TABLES;

END
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT 1 FROM pm_Permissions WHERE permission_tag = 'dbcorrectstructure')
```

Here `permission_tag = 'dbcorrectstructure'` but when you are inserting it is `'dbCorrectStructure'`...

Is it correct?, I think you should match the case also..

You should check like this `(SELECT 1 FROM pm_Permissions WHERE permission_tag = 'dbCorrectStructure')`

Comment: No, permission_tag is the fourth column in the table, and it doesn't contain any capital letters.

Comment: @user2834317 ohh sorry, I didn't knew that bdw `(SELECT 1 FROM pm_Permissions WHERE permission_tag = 'dbcorrectstructure')` is giving you any record? Can you show us the table structure of your table...